# ¿Quisiera saber una forma de encontrar la union de 3 conjuntos en pseint?

Tags: vectores, pseint, union

**conjuntos**

**A**(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)

**B**(3,4,5)

**C**(4,5)

**union**

**AuBuC**(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)

Comment: Saludos. Te falto agregar lo que probaste y que detalle tienes; ademas que tu planteamiento y tags no indica el lenguaje en que lo estas haciendo.

Comment: Hola José, bienvenido, tu pregunta se parece mucho a "tengo este ejercicio, resuélvanlo", este tipo de preguntas, no suelen ser bien recibidas, te sugiero que la edites, y muestres que has intentado, para saber que formas parte de la resolución de tu problema, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.